# Kendo Grid disable another column during cell editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had 2 radio buttons, if radio "**By %**" is checked only percentage field can be edit and the amount field will disable from editing. Same with radio "**Amount**", if it's checked the percentage field will be disable from editing and only amount field can be edit.

Since im using column.editor in my both columns. I try to apply this method, but none of it works. Or maybe I got wrong somewhere.

```js
// method 1
e.container.find("input[name='amount']").each(function () { $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled") });
// method 2
$("input[name=amount]").prop("disabled", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
// method 3
e.container.find("input[name='amount']").attr('disabled',true);
// method 4
if(e.container.find("[name]").first().attr("name") == "amount"){
  e.sender.closeCell();
}
```

[Here are the working demo in DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/OLiwagIr). Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the link you have given is it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, I tested it

```
 edit: function(e) {
          var radio_checked_value = $("input[name='radio_check']:checked").val();                       
          if(radio_checked_value == 'percentage'){
            var columnIndex = this.cellIndex(e.container);
            var fieldName = this.thead.find("th").eq(columnIndex).data("field");
            if(fieldName  === "amount"){
              this.closeCell();
            }
          }else{
            console.log('disable percentage field');
          }
}
```